# am I using Object.keys within a loop correctly?

Tags: javascript

```
 getCount = function(questions) {
     var i, questionCount, value;
      i = 0;
      console.log(questions);
      while (i < questions.length) {
        questionCount = 0;
        for (value in questions) {
          if (questions.hasOwnProperty(value)) {
            console.log(value);
            if (value > 0) {
              questionCount++;
            }
          }
        }
        i++;
        console.log(questionCount, 'COUNT');
      }
};

var questions = [ 
  {question : 'example question', 
   option : ['option 1' , 'option 2'], 
   value: 1]}, 
  {question : 'example question 2', 
   option : ['option 1' , 'option 2, option 3'], 
   value: 2]}
  ]
```

basically, I"m trying to count each time there is a value greater than 0 present within a question. But, when I console.log, I keep getting back what seems to be the length of questions.

the console.log(value) is showing me the index values 0 and 1, instead of the actual number of the value property.

Comment: The length of the questions is 2 and both questions have a value greater than 0 so you will get back 2 no?

Comment: when I alter the data, it seems to be counting the index values, rather than the actual number within the value property.

Comment: In your example, "questions" is an array, not an object.  So the for..in loop is looping over the array, which is redundant because the outer while loop is already doing that.  If all you want to do is check if the value key in each object is > 0, you don't need the for..in at all, just do if (questions[i].value > 0)....

Comment: The console is showing you the index values because that's how a for-in loop works in JavaScript. For each iteration, it sets the value of the index variable ("value" in this case) to the name of the object's next property. A JavaScript array is really just an object with numbers for property names. So your arrays each have one property named "0", and another property named "1" (and some other properties that you're filtering out with `hasOwnProperty`). That's what you're seeing in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a look at your code properly, it would be better to use a standard `for` loop as you are dealing with an array of objects.

The while loop is also unnecessary.

Consider something like the following snippet.

```js
(function(){
  var questions = [ 
    {
      question : 'example question', 
      option   : [
        'option 1' ,
        'option 2'
      ], 
      value    : 1
    }, 
    {
      question : 'example question 2', 
      option   : [
        'option 1',
        'option 2',
        'option 3'
      ], 
      value: 2
    }
  ],  
    getCount = function(questions) {
     var i = 0,
       questionCount = 0;
     for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
       if (questions[i].hasOwnProperty('value')) {
         if (questions[i].value > 0) {
           questionCount++;
         }
       }
      }
      return questionCount; 
     };
  console.info(getCount(questions));

  
}());
```

Hope that helps you out!

Answer (score 0):

Use [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method provided by Array

```
return questions.filter(function (question) {
        //filter question having positive value defined
        return !! question.value && question.value > 0;
}).length;
```